# Split a string with restrictions

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a string, but I want to split it removing the numbers and of course, the character that follows it, that are not equals the specified number.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String x = "32 X 28 Y 32 X 40 Y 36 X 32 Y 32 X 24 X 32 X";
    System.out.println(splittedArray(x, "\\s(?<!32)\\s").toString());
    // I know this regex is completely wrong.
}

private static List<String> splittedArray(String str, String regex) {
    return Arrays.asList(str.split(regex));
}
```

A better explanation:

Sample:

```
32 X 28 Y 32 X 40 Y 36 X 32 Y 32 X 24 X 32 X
```

If I want all 32 numbers and the character that follows, it should return:

```
32 X or 32X // Whatever
32 X
32 Y
32 X
32 X
```

I'm stuck to make it work, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ***"but I want to split it removing the numbers and of course"*** , then you say: ***"If I want all 32's number ...`32 X or 32X // Whatever` "***  what do you need exactly?

Comment: a string `tokenizer` might already be enough for your problem.

Comment: `(?:32\s\w).*?(?:32\s\w)` should work

Comment: @PedroLobito, I said I want to split removing all numbers that are not equal.. read until the end.

Comment: @Natecat, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle it using the `Pattern` and `Matcher`, rather than attempting to split the String.

**Edit**: updated the code to show how to collect into a `List<String>` and convert to `String[]` if desired.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // the sample input
    String x = "32 X 28 Y 32 X 40 Y 36 X 32 Y 32 X 24 X 32 X";

    // match based upon "32". This specific match can be made into
    // a String concat so the specific number may be specified
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\\s]*(32\\s[^\\d])");

    // get the matcher
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(x);

    // our collector
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    // while there are matches to be found
    while (m.find()) {
        // get the match
        String val = m.group().trim();
        System.out.println(val);

        // add to the collector
        res.add(val);
    }

    // sample conversion
    String[] asArray = res.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(asArray));
}
```

Returned Output based upon the sample input:

> 32 X
>   32 X
>   32 Y
>   32 X
>   32 X
>   [32 X, 32 X, 32 Y, 32 X, 32 X]

Comment: I need it as List because I have to make some other things with it.

Comment: @developer033, I would add each found entry to an `ArrayList<String>`. The s.o.p() just shows the found text. You can convert the `ArrayList<String>()` to a `String[]` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

thanks https://txt2re.com

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String txt="32 X 28 Y 32 X 40 Y 36 X 32 Y 32 X 24 X 32 X";

        String re1="(\\d+)";    // Integer Number 1
        String re2="(\\s+)";    // White Space 1
        String re3="(.)";   // Any Single Character 1

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        while (m.find())
        {
            String int1=m.group(1); //here's the number
            String c1=m.group(3); //here's the letter

            if (Integer.parseInt(int1) == 32) {
                System.out.println(int1.toString()+" "+c1.toString());  
            }
        }
    }

}
```